# Main error is "name 'self' is not defined"

Tags: python

You don't really need input data, and its extremely heavy to give the example here, code was working without ".self" and "**init**", but I really need to format it nice in separate functions like below. Thank you in advance!

```
class PlateString:

    def __init__(self, threshold=0.05):
        self.threshold = threshold
        max_list_from_all_plates = []

        for single_lp in seq:
            maximum_plate_prob = []
            possible_plate_prob = []
            max_list = []
            plateresults = []
            for sign in single_lp:
                high_indexes = []
                for prob_id in range(0,len(sign)):
                    if self.threshold<sign[prob_id]:
                        high_indexes.append([sign[prob_id], prob_id, CATEGORIES[prob_id]])
                max_list.append(high_indexes)

            max_list_from_all_plates.append(max_list)
            listaMain = []
            ListaVal = []
            self.checklen(max_list_from_all_plates, listaMain, ListaVal, plateresults)


    def checklen(self, max_list_from_all_plates, listaMain, ListaVal, plateresults):
            for plate in max_list_from_all_plates:
                maxlen = 0
                if len(plate) > maxlen:
                     maxlen = len(plate)
            print(maxlen)
textPlate : str= ""
            sumplate = 0 
            for probabilities in plate:
                znakMax : str = ""
                probabilityMax : float = 0
                for probability in probabilities:
                    if(probabilityMax<probability[0]):
                        probabilityMax = probability[0]
                        znakMax = probability[2]
                        valMax = probability[0]
                textPlate += znakMax
                sumplate += valMax
            listaMain.append(textPlate)
            ListaVal.append(sumplate)

            for i in range(len(listaMain)):
                info = [ListaVal[i], listaMain[i]]
                plateresults.append(info)
                                
            print(plateresults)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    PlateString(threshold=0.05).checklen(self, max_list_from_all_plates, listaMain, ListaVal, plateresults)
```

Comment: What does it mean that you "want to compare it by letters"? Do you want to sort the lists by the last element? If so, then use ``sorted`` with a ``key`` argument. As ``key`` you can add ``lambda x: x[2]``, meaning that you sort by the third element (a letter, in your case).

Comment: I don't want to use the sort function I want to make my own with simple logic operators like if a == b.

Comment: Can you provide `listyofechletter` so we understand how to get to your expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l = 0
counts = 0

```
for i in listyofechletter:
    r = 0
    r += r
    s = i[r]
    #print(i)
    if i[r] == i[r+1]:

        #print("the same",i)
        counts += 1

        res = sum(1 for x in listyofechletter if i[r] == i[r+1])
        #print(res, i)
        #if True:
        #counts =+ 1
    else:
        #print("not the same", i)
        res2 = sum(1 for y in listyofechletter if i[r] == i[r+1])



    
        print(res2,  i)

print(counts, i)
```

Problem was that I used =+ instead +=